# How to create dependencies between modules and providers (for refresh)

Tags: terraform

I'm having trouble getting dependencies to work correctly between modules in terraform.  The problem if'm having seems to be caused by dependencies not being evaluated correctly with respect to a provider.

I have:

- A docker container resource to setup rabbitmq in docker
- A timer resource dependent on rabbitmq container to ensure it's up
- Some rabbitmq resources to setup exchanges, queues, users etc.

This all works fine when everything is in the same module.  I just have to add the timer as a dependency to *everything* that will configure rabbitmq.

I now want to separate provisioning the docker container and configuring rabbitmq into different modules so that the configuration piece is reusable elsewhere.  I just can't seem to make one module wait on another.  It seems to always fail on refresh.

I've tried to make an output (of the module deploying the container) dependent on the sleep timer:

```
output "remote_host" {
  value = "localhost"
  depends_on = [time_sleep.rabbitmq_ready]
}
```

I've then used that output as an argument to the module:

```
module "rabbitmq" {
  source = "./modules/rabbitmq"
  api_url = "http://${module.container.remote_host}:15672"
  username = "admin"
  password = module.container.admin_password
}
```

In theory this should mean that the rabbitmq provider doesn't know how to connect until the container is fully up and running (until the sleep has completed).

But I get this, and the container isn't started at all:

```
module.rabbitmq.rabbitmq_queue.data_export: Refreshing state... [id=sites.data_export@/]

Error: Get "http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/sites.data_export": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:15672: connect: connection refused
```

What this shows is that the `depends_on = [time_sleep.rabbitmq_ready]` has been ignored during the refresh step and the value (`localhost`) is being returned without waiting for dependencies.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use outputs from module A as an argument for module B, and you therefore want module B to wait for module A.

The Terraform docs recommend using `depends_on` only as a last resort (see last paragraph of [Output Values page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html)), and instead structuring the files such that Terraform can figure out the dependencies by itself.

For example, with the following file structure:

```
.
+-- main.tf
+-- _vpc
|   +-- main.tf
|   +-- variables.tf
|   +-- outputs.tf
+-- _rds
|   +-- main.tf
|   +-- variables.tf
```

and the following included in `./main.tf`:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "./vpc"
}

module "rds" {
  source = "./rds"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = [ module.vpc.subnet_a_id , module.vpc.subnet_b_id, module.vpc.subnet_c_id ]
}
```

...any resources within module `rds` that use `var.vpc_id`  or `var.subnet_ids` will wait until those have been output by the `vpc` module.

Comment: The gotcha here is that the module boundary has no effect whatsoever.  As you say, terraform will wait until they outputs are ready.  For the question described here, nothing is delaying the outputs being read or could it.  The `time_sleep` is necessary to ensure the container has had chance to initialise, but no value at all is generated by that event.  So in this question the `depends_on` is already being used as a last resort and therefor unavoidable.

Comment: Are you using time values in your `time_sleep` @PhilipCouling as described in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep ?

Comment: as noted in the question, this all works when things are not divided into modules.  When the rabbitmq resources are directly dependent on the `time_sleep` this works.  But when I move those resources into a module they can't be directly dependent on things outside the module.  I've tried to get round this by making the *module* dependent on the same `time_sleep` but as described this doesn't work.  *short version; the `time_sleep` is correctly configured.*

Comment: @PhilipCouling -- is it just me, or is there a circular dependency here? The container module outputs `"remote_host"` and `depends_on` the rabbitmq module. And the rabbitmq module in turn consumes `{module.container.remote_host}` in one of its properties, and therefore implicitly depends on the container module. I wonder if this could be resolved through a script *after* Terraform is done, kind of like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743473/9754418

Comment: there’s no circular dependency here.  The rabbitmq config is dependent on having a rabbitmq container. Once again, I have this all working without wrapping anything up in a module. But terraform doesn’t seem to obey dependencies correctly with respect to modules.